# Use a member variable of class B in class A, when class B has an object of class A

Tags: c++, oop

Can I use a member variable of class B in class A, when class B has an object of class A ?
Like this code:

```
class A
{
public:
    int Aarr[B::Bnum];      
};

class B
{
public:
    A Aobject;
    static const int Bnum = 4;      
};
```

Comment: No that code doesn't compile. You might try a forward declaration of A and using a pointer or reference in class B.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois A forward declaration of `B` and using `B::Bnum` won't work.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois please solutions in the answer field, then they can be easier downvoted :P

Answer (score 0):

This exact arrangement is hardly necessary but here's how you may achieve a reasonable approximation of what you want:

```
class B
{
public:
    static const int Bnum = 4;
    class A
    {
    public:
        int Aarr[B::Bnum];
    };
    A Aobject;
};

using A = B::A;
```

Normally I'd put `Aobject` and `Bnum` declarations into separate classes, or move `Bnum` into a namespace instead.